# how to find out active record property through many to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm currently adjusting fedena to have a many:many relationship between students and guardians (as opposed to one:many student:guardians).

So this is what I did:

```
class Guardian < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :parentings, :dependent=>:destroy
  has_many   :students, :through=>:parentings
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :parentings, :dependent=>:destroy
  has_many   :guardians, :through=>:parentings
end

class Parenting < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :student_id, :guardian_id
    belongs_to :student
    belongs_to :guardian
end
```

inside [guardian.rb](https://github.com/projectfedena/fedena/blob/master/app/models/guardian.rb) there was this class method:

```
def self.shift_user(student)
  # find all the guardians having a ward_id = student.d (comment my own)
  self.find_all_by_ward_id(student.id).each do |g|
  ..
end
```

I want to change it using the newly defined relationshop ie

```
self.find_all_by_student_id(student.id).each do |g|
..
```

It doesn't work! I thought it would work since I've already defined that a Guardian has many students through the Parenting class.. I've tried several permutations of the command above and I keep on getting the error:

```
undefined method `find_all_by_student_id' for #<Class:0x1091c6b28>
```

ideas? I'm using `ruby 1.8.7` and `RoR 2.3.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Guardian` has no propety `student_id` so there is no method `find_all_by_student_id`. So I don't understand why you are confused. Why don't you just use `student.guardians`?

Comment: oh.. I think I didn't fully understand what Active Record actually does. I thought it would automagically add these properties to the objects it wraps around.. but I guess I was mistaken..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a named scope and a more complex query

```
class Guardian < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :parentings, :dependent=>:destroy
  has_many   :students, :through=>:parentings

  named_scope :find_all_by_student_id, lambda {|student_id| 
    { :all,
      :select => "guardians.*",
      :joins => "JOIN parentings ON parentings.guardian_id = guardians.id 
                 JOIN students ON students.id = parentings.student_id",
      :conditions = ["students.id = ?", student_id] } }
end
```